# How to initialize sObject with Relational fields?

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object, relationships, sobject

In Lightning component we have relational fields (e.g. CustObjA.CustObj__r.Name) which we use in lighthing component. This is on component as,

```
<ui:inputText class="slds-input" value="{!v.Item.CustObj__r.Name}" />
```

For existing objects we use SOQL to retrieve,

```
List<CustObjA> listObjs = [SELECT Startdate, CustObj__r.Name
FROM CustObjA];
```

This is working fine. But If we don't have records for the object, we would want to **initialize sObject CustObjA with relational fields**

I'm trying below approach.

```
List<CustObjA> listObjs = new List<CustObjA>();

CustObjA newObj = new CustObjA();
newObj.CustObj__c = new CustObj__c(name = 'test');

listObjs .add(newObj);
```

But this approach seems not resulting an object which I can refer **CustObj__r.Name**. Instead I'm getting below run-time exception.

> Attempt to de-reference a null object

What is the correct way of initializing an object with Relational fields?
Appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the name pointing reference:

```
MyObject__c record = new MyObject__c();
record.Parent__r = new Parent__c(Name='Populated');
```

---

The above is functionally equivalent to `putSObject`:

```
MyObject__c record = new MyObject__c();
record.putSObject('Parent__r', new Parent__c(Name='Populated'));
```

---

You can also use `name=value` pairs in the constructor for CPU savings:

```
 MyObject__c record = new MyObject__c(Parent__r=new Parent__c(Name='...'));
```

Comment: Any benchmark or documentation about this "CPU saving" ?

Comment: @SimonPlacentino I did some profiling [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/143896/2995). I realize you commented a long time ago, but I didn't see it.