# Cleaner way to filter specific object ids from List <String>?

Tags: apex, sobject, dml, merge

I am trying to update one of the related objects once the Account [merge](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_merge.htm) is completed.

```
Database.MergeResult results = Database.merge(masterAcct, duplicateAcct, false);
```

`getUpdatedRelatedIds()` method from the [MergeResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_database_mergeresult.htm#apex_Database_MergeResult_getUpdatedRelatedIds) class is giving me all the related Ids as `List<String>` but I want to filter a specific object from the list and update that record. So far I could only think of this way but let me know if there's a better way to do the same.

```
    List<String> returnedIds = new List<String>{'a812f000000CnFqAAK','a262f000000ndRnAAI','0012f00000lnY0rAAE'};
    List<Id> usefulIds = new List<Id>();
    for (String s : returnedIds)
    {
        if (String.valueOf(Id.valueOf(s).getSObjectType()) == 'UseFulObject__c'){
            usefulIds.add(s);
        }
    }
List<UseFulObject__c> updateUsefulRecords = new List<UseFulObject__c>();
    for (Id s: usefulIds){
        UseFulObject__c uo = (UseFulObject__c) s.getSObjectType().newSObject(s);
        uo.IsActive__c = false;
        updateUsefulRecords.add(uo);
    }
    
    update updateUsefulRecords ;
```

Comment: Code readibility wise, this approach looks fine.

Comment: @Raul How about performance wise? Would there be an impact if the returnedIds are in 1000s?

Comment: Code looks good to me, although if you can reduce the second for loop. Add the logic in the first for-loop if criteria.

Comment: @Piyush Did you mean something like this?

if (Id.valueOf(s).getSObjectType() == UseFulObject__c.SObjectType){
        UseFulObject__c sa = (UseFulObject__c ) Id.valueOf(s).getSObjectType().newSObject(Id.valueOf(s));
        sa.IsActive__c = false;
        sa.Name = sa.Name+'_MERGE';
     updateUsefulRecords.add(sa);
    }

Comment: @SunnyG Yes, This way you can reduce for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have already looks good. The only optimization I see is you can just compare the token directly, you don't need `String.valueOf`.

```
if (Id.valueOf(s).getSObjectType() == UsefulObject__c.sObjectType)
```

Comment: Didn't know about that, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the simplified type check that @Adrian Larson pointed out, you can also change:

```java
UseFulObject__c uo = (UseFulObject__c) s.getSObjectType().newSObject(s);
uo.IsActive__c = false;
updateUsefulRecords.add(uo);
```

to:

```java
updateUsefulRecords.add(new UsefulObject__c(Id = s, IsActive__c = false));
```

There's no need to be jumping hoops to work out what to create given that you hard-coded the type cast anyway, and setting all necessary fields in an SObject constructor is slightly more efficient (it depends just how many fields you need to set on how many records really).

Comment: Setting fields in the SObject constructor takes less of the CPU limit, [but the difference is miniscule](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143891/how-to-avoid-instantiating-object-inside-a-loop/143900#143900). Like 0.016 vs 0.024 CPU per field-record. That's a maximum of 80 CPU limit for 10k records. Getting rid of the `getSObjectType().newSObject()` probably has more of an impact, but at the cost of some flexibility (though OP would need to use a `List<SObject>` and SObject's `.set()`, and sort the list prior to dml, and not hard-code the SObject type to get full flexixbility).

Comment: Is there a way to retain field values of existing record by passing the Id ? I am only updating boolean property at this point but If I want to append to a prior value of a text field, is that something possible with this implementation? Or I have to query to do so?

Comment: @DerekF the OP makes no mention of needing "flexibility" so my suggested change is only for the better (even if you picked up more on the performance aspect of the constructor than on the avoidance of use of `s.getSObjectType().newSObject(s)` which was my primary change. I guess I should have provided my explanation in the opposite order.

Comment: @SunnyG you can always query the original records with the required text field and then use that as part of your update. The 'only setting the fields I really need to update' approach you have used is definitely correct; if you include irrelevant fields you risk causing lost of concurrent changes to those fields otherwise.

Comment: @DerekF That test you linked was written incorrectly. `Limits.getCpuTime()` is grossly inaccurate for profiling Apex, `DateTime.now().getTime()` is much better. The actual cost of dot notation is indeed about 2x, and that cost can be significant depending on the number of fields you need to set.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks